# Firebase 3 database debug output when connecting from node.js SDKerv

Tags: debugging, firebase, firebase-security, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

Recently upgrading to run the firebase 3 sdk both in the client, in e2e tests and on the server.

Previously when using the firebase 2.x sdk you could connect to firebase in the same was as a client using signInWithCustomToken. This meant I could generate a token with the {debug: true} flag and use this for my mocha tests. Meaning I would get verbose output from firebase in the invent of security rejection.

Firebase 3 does not allow you to use client types of auth when running the sdk from node (i.e mocha). You must use service accounts. I have created the service account and have serviceaccount.json. I can connect and spoof the UID by using databaseAuthVariableOverride and everything is running AOK but I cannot figure out how to get firebase to send verbose database output so I can debug new firebase rules from my tests.

I have tried things like adding "Log Viewer" permission to my service account. I have also tried (in vein) to add debug: true to the serviceaccount.json

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 4):

Have you tried the following (in Node.js):

```
firebase.database.enableLogging(true);
```